# How to use sqlalchemy-migrate with declarative db model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I try add to some table new column, how its described in documentation for sqlalchemy-migrate< like:

```
col = Column('col1', String, default='foobar')
col.create(table, populate_default=True)
```

But I get error, i think its because i use declarative models, how i can use migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def upgrade(migrate_engine):
    Base.metadata.bind = migrate_engine
    col = Column('col1', String, default='foobar')
    col.create(table, populate_default=True)`
```

worked for me.